# Eclipse CDT Mars: Input from a file

Tags: c, eclipse, user-input, eclipse-cdt

I have recently installed Eclipse CDT Mars release for running C Programs. I am facing problems with taking input from a file. So, I have a program that looks like this:

```
int main(void) {

//Declarations
int number_of_segments;
int k_constraint;
segment_node *ptr_to_segment_array, *ptr_to_segment_sorted_array;
int no_of_coordinates;
int *ptr_to_solution_array;
int *ptr_to_list_of_segment_identifiers_currently;
int no_of_identifiers_currently=1;
int i,j=1,k=0, l=0;

//setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);
//Input
printf("Enter the number of segments\n");
scanf("%d", &number_of_segments);
printf("Enter the k constraint \n");
scanf("%d", &k_constraint);

no_of_coordinates = number_of_segments*2;
//Dynamically allocate memory to the Array
ptr_to_segment_array = (segment_node*)malloc(sizeof(segment_node)*no_of_coordinates);
ptr_to_segment_sorted_array = (segment_node*)malloc(sizeof(segment_node)*no_of_coordinates);
ptr_to_solution_array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*no_of_coordinates);
ptr_to_list_of_segment_identifiers_currently = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*number_of_segments);

/*Now, input the individual segments's coordinates from left to right
** while also assigning the unique numbers to an individual segments' coordinates*/
printf("Enter the coordinates of segments from left to right \n");
for(i=0; i<no_of_coordinates; i++,j++){
    scanf(" %d", &(ptr_to_segment_array[i].coordinate));
    if(j==1){
        ptr_to_segment_array[i].position = 'l';
        ptr_to_segment_array[i].identifier = i+1;
    }
    else if(j==2){
        ptr_to_segment_array[i].position = 'r';
        ptr_to_segment_array[i].identifier = i+1;
    }
    if(j==2){
        //Reset
        j=1;
    }

}
return 0;
}
```

Well, of course its not the whole program. This is the glimpse of it. The problem is the scanf statements are supposed to take input and I want the input to be taken from a file. So, I did the following:

1. First I created a text file with the following contents(inputs), in the workspace directory itself.
   3
   2
   -3
   2
   0
   5
   3
   8
2. Then, I configured Eclipse to take input from the console.
   [image]

Notice that the Encoding has been set to MS932(default)

Now, I build it and debug it. I step up to the Input step. Then, I wait for like minutes and nothing. That's it. The program seems to be taking long time but control doesn't move to the next line.

Now, you may think that there is some fault in the program itself and yeah it may be but I also ran this program on Ideone.com with custom inputs and it does take the inputs. Also, I ran this program with input from  Console and it did take the inputs properly step by step.

So, why it wouldn't take inputs from a file directly this way? Is it an encoding issue with Notepad/Eclipse or something else?

Any help is appreciated. 
**Btw, if anyone wants the complete program, I am happy to provide it. Its not some proprietary content. I wrote purely for educational purpose as solution to some problem.**

Comment: @Olaf : Removed one of them. The other one is necessary to show the configuration.

Comment: THere should be another way. The text is unreadable.

Comment: @Olaf Okay, then I can describe it. It is just the Common Tab in Run-> Run Configuration in Eclipse where you specify the input file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen that you tell your program to read from file. So it just waits your input.
You should add this at the beginning:

```
freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
```

What it does: it `reopen`s `stdin` file descriptor and attaches `input.txt` to it. It attaches it for reading - second argument is `"r"`

But if you want to be able to read from console AND files, you need to add one more:

```
FILE *in;
in = fopen("input.txt", "r");
```

And you should replace `scanf(...)` with `fscanf(in, ...)`

```
fscanf(in, "%d", number);
```

Comment: Actually, the Configuration window in Eclipse Mars give option to provide the file path, See the image. Wouldn't that provide it?

Comment: @pulp_fiction I'm not sure, maybe it's Eclipse bug (or feature). But why you use this if you have built-in C features?

Comment: I am trying your solution. Will post the results.

Comment: Yep, your solution works definitely. Would be an added bonus if someone could tell me about the Input feature in the Commons Tab in Eclipse Mars CDT. Thank You btw.